# Распределение текста по двум или более колонкам

Tags: c#, office, office-interop

Есть таблица в word, генерит цикл. Таблица простая, состоит из двух колонок и множества строк. Нужно эту таблицу расположить в одном листе на две или более колонки. Если все делать руками, то выделяется таблица и указывается сколько колонок надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как такое же реализовать через API? В данный момент использую стороннее решение NetOffice.WordApi. В принципе там функциональность от Office.Interop.Word.
Ниже код генерит таблицу и выделяет его. Через какие механизмы разбить его по колонкам?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string _pathFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "TableRow.docx");
        if (!File.Exists(_pathFile))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Файл не найден", _pathFile);

        using (var app = new NetOffice.WordApi.Application { Visible = true })
        {
            using (var document = app.Documents.Open(_pathFile))
            {
                var table = document.Bookmarks["Table"].Range.Tables[1];
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    table.Rows.Add();
                }
                table.Range.Select();

                //Чё дальше?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170455/12888024). Вот [еще решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49016730/12888024) для PowerShell с использованием того же самого `Word.Interop`, думаю на C# не составит труда перевести.

Comment: Спасибо, почти то что нужно. Только table.Range.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2) всю страницу на колонки разбивает, а надо лишь таблицу. Есть хоть куда копать дальше.

Comment: Так у вас на скришоте показано разбиение страницы на колонки, а не таблицы. Исправьте вопрос.

Comment: [`table.Columns.Add(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.columns?view=word-pia)

Comment: На скриншоте все правильно. Там если выделить таблицу, то только он разбивается на колонки.

Comment: Странно, у меня эта же операция в ворде разбивает страницу, а не таблицу, только что проверил. Может просто у меня ворд новый, а у вас старый. В общем, ссылка на нужный метод выше.

Comment: Возможно у меня word старый. Office 2010.
вот скрин https://yadi.sk/i/r2Dxtl4eSlzFQA

Comment: Ну, оно разбивает вам страницу на 2 колонки, получается 2 таблицы, по 2 колонки в каждой. Именно это и делает операция, которую я посоветовал вам в первом сообщении. Вы лучше сначала все попробуйте, а потом говорите, что не работает, а не наоборот.

Comment: Первое, то что скинули работает. Вот я ручками создал шапку, длинную таблицу выделил его и кликнул на "Колонки" выбрал 2 и я получил, что шапка осталась не тронутой, а таблицу разбил на две колонки. Тоже самое хочу воспроизвести через код. Вот сейчас вникаю про Selection.InsertBreak(). А метод который скинули table.Columns.Add(...), это не то. Мне не нужно добавлять колонки к таблице.

Comment: Я понял в чем вас запутал. Попробую распутать. Давайте так: КолонкаТаблица - это колонка таблицы, а КолонкаКолонка - это опция офиса, называется "Распределение текста по двум или более колонкам". Так вот...
**"таблицу разбил на две КолонкаКолонка"**
**"Мне не нужно добавлять КолонкаТаблица к таблице"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно разбить страницу на 2 колонки в том месте, где находится таблица

```csharp
table.Range.InsertBreak(NetOffice.WordApi.Enums.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous);
document.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2);
```

`table.Range.Select()` при этом делать не обязательно.

Comment: Допилил, так как надо. Спасибо за наводки.